# Background image css animate() within setInterval() function call in JQuery

Tags: css, jquery

I have noticed a behaviour that I can't explain.  I'm sure it must be my limited knowledge of JQuery/JavaScript.

When I run the following code on my webpage, everything works as expected - the background image rotates:

```
//background image rotator
var imgArr = new Array('/images/1.jpg', '/images/2.jpg', '/images/3.jpg');
var preloadArr = new Array();
var i;

/* preload images */
for (i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    preloadArr[i] = new Image();
    preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];
}

var currImg = 1;
var intID = setInterval(changeImg, 5000);

function changeImg() {
    $('#homeDiv').css({ 'background': 'url(' +  preloadArr[currImg++ % preloadArr.length].src + ')' });
}
```

However, if I replace the `.css()` function with `.animate()`, like in the following code, the `currImg++` seems to increment by 2 and an incorrect image loads.

```
//background image rotator
var imgArr = new Array('/images/1.jpg', '/images/2.jpg', '/images/3.jpg');
var preloadArr = new Array();
var i;

/* preload images */
for (i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    preloadArr[i] = new Image();
    preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];
}

var currImg = 1;
var intID = setInterval(changeImg, 5000);

function changeImg() {
    $('#homeDiv').animate({ 'background': 'url(' +  preloadArr[currImg++ % preloadArr.length].src + ')' }, 1000);
}
```

Is it due to the `setInterval` process getting 'out of sync' due to the `animate()` function taking 1000ms?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the setInterval and write code like this

```
function changeImg() {
$('#homeDiv').delay(5000).animate({ 'background': 'url(' +  preloadArr[currImg++ % preloadArr.length].src + ')' }, 1000, function() { changeImg();} );
}
```

Like you said, setInterval gets asynchronous with animate function. Here chaneImg runs itself again as callback function everytime it's done executing itself.